# Node.js error on Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a node.js application which is running seemless on my locale machine. However i'm currently not able to make it run within azure because of the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_extend'
    at Function.init (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\finalhandler\node_modules\debug\src\node.js:234:28)
    at createDebug (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\finalhandler\node_modules\debug\src\debug.js:124:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js:14:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:16:20)
```

I tried already several solutions since i assume the origin of the error lies within the node module version used on azure web app services. However even changing the node version to the same i have locally didn't do the trick. In addition to prevent package correlation issues with my local installs i using a npm-shrinkwrap.

Has anyone got into the same troubles and might has a solution or a hint where to look further?

Comment: Could you provide your `package.json` file?

Comment: hi @AronChen you can find the json and the shrinkwrap here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AldGdcl6FYQEmbo7xRZzcoWMRFdoeQ
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AldGdcl6FYQEmbo8sZFlZddxbaZMOw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps) may answer your question.

> Azure App Service does not support all native modules and might fail at compiling those with very specific prerequisites. Two workarounds proved successful with almost all native modules available today:
>
> - Run **npm install** on a Windows machine that has all the native module's prerequisites installed. Then, deploy the created `node_modules` folder as part of the application to Azure App Service.
> - Azure App Service can be configured to execute custom bash or shell scripts during deployment, giving you the opportunity to execute custom commands and precisely configure the way **npm install** is being run. For a video showing how to do this, see [Custom Website Deployment Scripts with Kudu](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/custom-web-site-deployment-scripts-with-kudu/).